# events.js:72 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event ^ Error: listen EACCES on OpenShift

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, deployment, openshift

I am trying to make a simple chat app. It **works fine on localhost:3000/chat.html**, but when it is deployed on **OpenShift**, it crashes with the following error: (After I `rhc tail` the log)

**EDIT: I don't get this error any more**

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: listen EACCES
    at errnoException (net.js:905:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1024:19)
    at listen (net.js:1065:10)
    at net.js:1147:9
    at dns.js:72:18
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:442:13)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:499:11)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:929:3
DEBUG: Program node server.js exited with code 8
DEBUG: Starting child process with 'node server.js'
```

I have read similar posts about this error, which didn't solve my problem. 1) I am binding at a high `port (3000)`
2) My address is not in use (otherwise, I will get `EADDRRINUSE`) 3) I have another application on *OpenShift* that is listening to `port 3000`, but I think they shouldn't affect each other because the *domain* is different

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "chat",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.15.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "express-session": "^1.14.2",
    "multer": "^1.1.0",
    "sockjs": "^0.3.18"
  }
}
```

Here is my server.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var session      = require('express-session');

var http = require('http');
var sockjs = require('sockjs');

var connections = [];
var chat = sockjs.createServer();
chat.on('connection', function(conn) {
    connections.push(conn);
    var number = connections.length;
    conn.write("Welcome, User " + number);
    conn.on('data', function(message) {

        for (var ii=0; ii < connections.length; ii++) {
            connections[ii].write("User " + number + " says: " + message);
        }
    });
    conn.on('close', function() {
        for (var ii=0; ii < connections.length; ii++) {
            connections[ii].write("User " + number + " has disconnected");
        }
    });
});

var server = http.createServer();
chat.installHandlers(server, {prefix:'/chat'});
server.listen(9999, '127.0.0.1');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

var ipaddress = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '127.0.0.1';
var port      = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 3000;

app.listen(port, ipaddress, function () {
    console.log( "Listening on " + ipaddress + ", port " + port )
});
```

I have **pinned down** the error at this portion of the `server.js`, if I comment it out, the chat will obviously not work, but I can deploy it on *OpenShift*. Am I creating the `socket` or `HTTP` server wrong on *OpenShift*?

```
var connections = [];
var chat = sockjs.createServer();
chat.on('connection', function(conn) {
    connections.push(conn);
    var number = connections.length;
    conn.write("Welcome, User " + number);
    conn.on('data', function(message) {

        for (var ii=0; ii < connections.length; ii++) {
            connections[ii].write("User " + number + " says: " + message);
        }
    });
    conn.on('close', function() {
        for (var ii=0; ii < connections.length; ii++) {
            connections[ii].write("User " + number + " has disconnected");
        }
    });
});

var server = http.createServer();
chat.installHandlers(server, {prefix:'/chat'});
server.listen(9999, '127.0.0.1');
```

**EDIT:**

<s>Instead of:</s>

```
var server = http.createServer();
chat.installHandlers(server, {prefix:'/chat'});
server.listen(9999, '127.0.0.1');
```

tried this and also didn't work on **OpenShift**, also works fine on **localhost:3000/chat.html**

```
app.set('port', 9999);
var server = http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
chat.installHandlers(server, {prefix:'/chat'});
```

**EDIT:**
After I put this line all the way in the top

```
var ipaddress = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '127.0.0.1';
```

Instead of:

```
var server = http.createServer();
chat.installHandlers(server, {prefix:'/chat'});
server.listen(9999, '127.0.0.1');
```

I have:

```
var server = http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), ipaddress, function(){
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port') + ', ip: ' + ipaddress);
});
chat.installHandlers(server, {prefix:'/chat'});
```

Now, it doesn't crash any more, but the http server is not listening.

**DEBUG INFO:**

1) localhost:

```
Http server listening on port 9999, ip: 127.0.0.1
Express server listening on 127.0.0.1, port 3000
```

OpenShit:

```
Http server listening on port 9999, ip: 127.5.69.129
Express server listening on 127.5.69.129, port 8080
```

2) Just found out that, when I run the application locally, then both my `localhost` and *OpenShift* are working locally on my machine. If I use my phone to get on the same *OpenShift* link, the `http` server is not listening, so I cannot chat.

Answer (score 0):

based on the information above, the short freenode chat we just had and the two files we had a look at:

- https://github.com/kz4/EasyChat/blob/master/public/chat.html
- https://github.com/kz4/EasyChat/blob/master/server.js

your generated html code contains a javascript function that is trying to connect to localhost:9999 - and that is why without a local server running, the clients will fail to connect.

i am no nodejs expert, so i can not comment on the root cause from a nodejs perspective, but i'd suggest looking at how to properly configure the reverse connection created from the client.

Comment: I manually replaced the 127.0.0.1 in chat.html to 127.5.69.129 (Openshift IP) and it still didn't work. The socket connection on port 9999 isn't established, because if it's established, it will display "Welcome, User 1" (from server.js). Nothing is displayed, maybe there is more than just IP and port? I have updated my code on GIthub as well

Comment: Maybe it does have something to do with port number? https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/port-binding-routing.html or OpenShift doesn't allow two ports?

Comment: @HoKy22 of course it didn't work when you replaced 127.0.0.1 with an IP - this is a random internal OpenShift IP assigned to your gear. you need to: 1. use your public hostname and port 80 or 443 to access your application from the client; 2. make sure this is http traffic *only*; 3. make sure the OpenShift broker knows what internal service to redirect that traffic to (i.e. decide either on port 9999 or 3000 but not both)

Comment: I know manually set it with an IP is bad but seems like OpenShift just assigns that IP for me. I did that because it's on the client side it has no access to process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP. I was able to make the openshift IP as a REST service on server.js, but on the client side, controller has access to it, that sockjs is global, so not sure how to do it. So, you mean I only need 3000 or 9999 for express server? For the sockjs server client communication, I am using 9999 now, are you saying I have to use 80 instead?

Comment: yes, you only have entry points into openshift through ports 80 and 443 (your node's reverse proxy ports) so your client must be using either one of those. the openshift node you were assigned to will then forward those requests to your gear. see the diagram here for a graphical representation:
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/OpenShift_Enterprise/2/html/Deployment_Guide/Security8.html

Comment: and not to forget - *always* use the hostname you chose for the application from external connections, *never* the ip. the hostname is the lookup key for the reverse proxy - it is the only way it can tell what gear to forward your request to.